# How to zip only the current directory with System.IO.Compression

Tags: c#, .net

It's not obvious there is a method or parameter that does this.

[`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485707%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) includes all subdirectories

I could loop the current directory files and add to a zip file with
`ZipArchive` but this assumes there is already a ZIP file that exists to add files to. Unless I create an empty ZIP file somewhere and copy that to the destination, but this seems inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind just found out this creates a new empty zip file.

```
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(item.Path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(item.Path2, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                {
                    zip.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath, Path.GetFileName(filePath));
                }
            }
```